# Concatenate right an input

Tags: php

I am trying to concatenate this code but i can not do it right

```
echo '<input type="text" id="text" name="username" 

value=".<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['.'rememberme'.']))

{echo $_COOKIE['.'remember me'.'];}?>." 

placeholder="Username"/><br />';
```

Comment: You're already in PHP, why are you `<?php`ing?

Comment: i tryed every possibility but it does not working

Comment: @Filip Well, stop trying and read a tutorial on PHP. You're not going to win this one through brute-force, there are *way* too many things wrong with what you're doing. This is fundamental PHP, just spend a little time *learning* it before doing it and you shouldn't have any trouble.

Comment: @meagar Wise words. A shame almost nobody seems to bother with [the "learn" part](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)...

Comment: @meaga I try to learn im only 17 and just started to learn php

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol gave me the solution

Comment: @Filip Yes, this is pretty much what my comment assumed...

Comment: @Filip I was 16 when I started PHP. I was doing the PHP equivalent of casting fireballs within a week. It's really easy to learn, if you're willing to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already in PHP there...

```
<?php
echo '<input type="text" id="text" name="username"';
if( isset($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) echo ' value="'.htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['rememberme']).'"';
echo ' placeholder="Username" /><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf('<input type="text" id="text" name="username" value="%s" placeholder="Username"/><br />', 
    (isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['remember_me']) : ''
);
```